# Rails create a stopwatch parameter in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, models

I need to create a time based countdown model attribute such that I can just call it in the view like

```
<%=Merge.timer%>
```

and have an output like:

```
#22:39
#22:38
#22:37...
```

I have Merge as a model that may or may not have a lot of entries and in my view i have to call

```
<%merge_lists.each do |i|%>
<%end%>
```

so for each `merge`, i want to have a countdown till expiration. which really depends on when the `merge` was creates. Say each `merge` lasts 7hours each.

Comment: Why not do it entirely in javascript?

Comment: because if i do, the timer will restart everytime it is rendered

Comment: No, you should just know what the goal time is. This could be given by the model. The logic and countdown could be written in a few lines of JS.

Comment: Let me edit the question, so maybe you will understand better

Comment: I'd store the end time in the db and calculate the time remaining in a method. Is this what you're asking? It's hard to tell from the question.

Comment: thanks, this could work. Can I have a code example of the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, I'd store the end time in the database and calculate the time remaining in a method.

To store the time, you can use a timestamp.

```
rails g model merge end_time:timestamp
```

Or, if you have already created the model...

```
rails generate migration add_end_time_to_merge end_time:timestamp
```

You can calculate the end time using a Time object, which can be created as below. You need to do this at the creation of every `Merge`, which will probably be in the controller.

```
@merge.end_time = 6.hours.since # for some reason, this means 7.
```

The code to calculate the time remaining should go in the model.

```
class Merge < ApplicationRecord
  def time_remaining
    Time.at(end_time - Time.now)
  end

  def timer
    time_remaining.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
  end
end
```

The `timer` method outputs the time remaining in a string, such as `"06:49:23"`.

The biggest problem is how to keep updating it in the view file. Ruby runs only once - before the page has reached the user. For it to keep updating, you will need to use some JS.

```
function updateTime() {
  var address = "<%= @address_to_time %>";
  $.get(address, function(data) {  // Send Ajax request
    $("#time").html(data);         // Update contents of container
    updateTime();                  // Repeat when finished
  });
}
updateTime();
```

You can make the time available through a partial, which renders only the HTML to display the time. Provide the address to this in `@address_to_time`.

Comment: If anyone knows why `7.hours.since` isn't working properly, please edit or comment here. Thank you.

Comment: `6.hours.from_now` should be correct. It looks different because it might be displayed in UTC.